# How to register HttpClient that will authenticate domain user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

I have to configure HttpClient to automatically pass Windows credentials (company API that I'm calling is using Windows Authentication). So far I was creating HttpClient inside my methods like so:

```
var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache {{
  new Uri("https://localhost"),
  "NTLM",
  CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
 }};
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentialsCache };
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

but since this could lead to socket exhaustion I want to use factory. Therefore inside `Startup.cs` I would add HttpClient like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 // ...
 services.AddHttpClient();
}
```

Then I would inject factory into my service via constructor:

```
public class MyService
{
 private readonly IHttpClientFactory clientFactory;
 public MyService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
 {
  this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
 }
 public async Task MakeHttpRequest()
 {
  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost/endpoint");
  var client = clientFactory.CreateClient();
  var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
  // ...
 }
}
```

How can I configure client created this way to use network credentials? Ideally I would like to configure this only once, inside `ConfigureServices()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the options pattern to set configuration for how `IHttpClientFactory` creates the `HttpClient`. You can configure these options in the following ways

Un-named options, these will apply to all instances of `HttpClient` that are created by the factory

```
services.Configure<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(options =>
{
    options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(builder =>
    {
        var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache {{
            new Uri("https://localhost"),
            "NTLM",
            CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
        }};
        builder.PrimaryHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentialsCache };
    });
});
```

Named options, these only apply to instances of `HttpClient` where you pass the name to the `CreateClient` method on the factory

```
services.Configure<HttpClientFactoryOptions>("myclient", options =>
{
    options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(builder =>
    {
        var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache {{
            new Uri("https://localhost"),
            "NTLM",
            CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
        }};
        builder.PrimaryHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentialsCache };
    });
});
```

To use the named options you would do

```
var client = clientFactory.CreateClient("myclient");
```

Comment: This is brilliant as I can still use unnamed clients. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You may look at [named clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#named-clients) and use [`ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configureprimaryhttpmessagehandler?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientBuilderExtensions.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) method then

```cs
services
    .AddHttpClient("myService")
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Credentials = credentialsCache
    });
```

`HttpClient` in `MyService` should be created using the given name

```cs
...
var client = clientFactory.CreateClient("myService");
...
```

Comment: Thank you! The bit I was missing was that ````AddHttpClient()```` is returning ````IServiceCollection```` whilst ````AddHttpClient("name")```` is returning ````IHttpClientBuilder```` that defines ````ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler()```` method